# try/catch + using, right syntax

Tags: c#, try-catch, using-statement

Which one:

```
using (var myObject = new MyClass())
{
   try
   {
      // something here...
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      // Handle exception
   }
}
```

OR

```
try
{
   using (var myObject = new MyClass())
   {
      // something here...
   }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: Just a note: one should be careful to only catch exceptions that can actually be _handled_ (corrected), except for logging, or wrapping them.

Comment: Please keep in mind that also the last `}` of the `using` statement can throw an exception [as reminded here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: TIL that the debugger (in VS) will not call the dispose method if you use the first block of code. Because the using statement itself can throw an exception, it help me to use the second block to ensure the implied `finally` called the dispose method.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I prefer the second one. May as well trap errors relating to the creation of the object as well.

Comment: I disagree with this advice. If you are expecting the object creation to throw an error, then any handling of that exception *must* go outside. If there is some question about where the handling should go, then the exception that is expected must be something else—unless you are advocating catching any random exception that may or may not be anticipated, which is a classic anti-pattern (outside of a process or thread's Unhandled Exception Handler).

Comment: @Jeffrey: The approach I described has served me well and I've been doing this a long time. No one said anything about *expecting* object creation to fail. But by wrapping an operation that could *potentially* fail in a `try` block, which allows you to pop an error message if something fails, the program now has the ability to recover and inform the user.

Comment: Your answer is correct but continues the suggestion that the try/catch _has_ to be there (immediately) at all times.

Comment: I think first one has merit as well, consider a DB transaction `using( DBConnection conn = DBFactory.getConnection())` which would need to be rolled back in case of an exception that occurred. Seems to me that both have their place.

Comment: @wfoster In that case you'd probably better always rollback the transaction when `using` exits, except in case of an explicit commit.

Comment: That will also trap errors related to the **disposal** of the object.

Comment: @JasonC: That new syntax is nothing more than syntactic sugar that simply uses the current code block to determine scope. It does not make this question moot. You can still control that scope.

Comment: @JonathanWood Yes; you are correct and I knew this. I'm really not sure why I wrote "moot" , I'm going to blame that one on lack of coffee. Sorry about that; thanks for calling it out.

Comment: Let's try this again: Also, C# 8 added a neat new syntax that makes both forms a bit more concise ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) and I've got an example below). The main difference is, if the OP's example has code after those `using` blocks, the new syntax doesn't do much if you're looking for an *exact* match to the scope of the examples. But I've found that in most cases, it helps.

Comment: @JasonC: My point was that, using the new syntax, you can still choose whether the `using` statement goes before the `try` block or within it. That would duplicate the two variations he originally asked about.

Answer (score 53):

Since a using block is just a syntax simplification of a try/finally ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)), personally I'd go with the following, though I doubt it's significantly different than your second option:

```
MyClass myObject = null;

try
{
    myObject = new MyClass();
    //important stuff
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //handle exception
}
finally
{
    if (myObject is IDisposable)
    {
        myObject.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think adding a `finally` block is preferable to the `using` statement?

Comment: Adding a `finally` block that disposes an IDisposable object is what a `using` statement does.  Personally, I like this instead of the embedded `using` block because I think it more cleanly states where everything is happening, and that it's all on the same "level".  I also like this more than several embedded `using` blocks... but it's all just my preference.

Comment: If you implement much exception handling, you must really enjoy typing! That "using" keyword has been around for a while and it's meaning is quite clear to me. And using it helps make the rest of my code clearer by keeping the amount of clutter to a minimum.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The object must be instantiated outside the `try` statement for it to be disposed within the `finally` statement; otherwise, it will throw a compiler error: "Use of unassigned local variable 'myObject'"

Comment: @SteveKonves, I suppose you're technically correct, the first line should be `var myObject=null;` ...Though I wouldn't consider that a downfall of any pseudo-code...

Comment: Technically, that won't compile either. `Cannot assign null to implicitly-typed local variable` ;) But I know what you mean and personally would prefer this to nesting a using block.

Comment: @chezy525 Why are you using the typecast in the finally? Is this really needed in .NET 3.5 or later? Before?

Comment: @chezy525 Could your finally throw another type cast exception?

Comment: @MartinMeeser, I suppose whether or not you need a typecast in the finally block depends on how you setup your variable (as a `var`, or other base class that isn't required to be an `IDisposable`, it is needed).  However, I believe you may be correct that, as it was, the code could throw a typecast exception in the finally block (It should be fixed now).

Comment: `finally { myObject?.Dispose() }` will be same with `finally { if(myObject == null) myObject.Dispose() }` You don't need to safe cast variable again because you already know that it is instantiated from MyClass. Cheaper one is null check.

Comment: I agree this is much more clear. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 22):

It depends. If you are using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), `using(...) { try... }` will not work correctly if the proxy in `using` statement is in exception state, i.e. Disposing this proxy will cause another exception.

Personally, I believe in minimal handling approach, i.e. handle only exception you are aware of at the point of execution. In other word, if you know that the initialization of a variable in `using` may throw a particular exception, I wrap it with `try-catch`. Similarly, if within `using` body something may happen, which is not directly related to the variable in `using`, then I wrap it with another `try` for that particular exception. I rarely use `Exception` in my `catch`es.

But I do like `IDisposable` and `using` though so I maybe biased.

Answer (score 21):

If your catch statement needs to access the variable declared in a using statement, then inside is your only option.

If your catch statement needs the object referenced in the using before it is disposed, then inside is your only option.

If your catch statement takes an action of unknown duration, like displaying a message to the user, and you would like to dispose of your resources before that happens, then outside is your best option.

Whenever I have a scenerio similar to this, the try-catch block is usually in a different method further up the call stack from the using. It is not typical for a method to know how to handle exceptions that occur within it like this.

So my general recomendation is outside—way outside.

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        SaveFile(myFile); // The using statement will appear somewhere in here.
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Both are valid syntax. It really comes down to what you want to do: if you want to catch errors relating to creating/disposing the object, use the second. If not, use the first.

Answer (score 9):

There is one important thing which I'll call out here: The first one will **not** catch any exception arising out of calling the `MyClass` constructor.

Answer (score 8):

From [C# 8.0 on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), you can simplify `using` statements under some conditions to get rid of the nested block, and then it just applies to the enclosing block.

So your two examples can be reduced to:

```
using var myObject = new MyClass();
try
{
   // something here...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // Handle exception
}
```

And:

```
try
{
   using var myObject = new MyClass();
   // something here...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // Handle exception
}
```

Both of which are pretty clear; and then that reduces the choice between the two to a matter of what you want the scope of the object to be, where you want to handle instantiation errors, and when you want to dispose of it.

Comment: this is the new best answer

Answer (score 2):

If the object you are initializing in the Using() block might throw any exception then you should go for the second syntax otherwise both the equally valid.

In my scenario, I had to open a file and I was passing filePath in the constructor of the object which I was initializing in the Using() block and it might throw exception if the filePath is wrong/empty. So in this case, second syntax makes sense.

My sample code :-

```
try
{
    using (var obj= new MyClass("fileName.extension"))
    {

    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     //Take actions according to the exception.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From C# 8.0, I prefer to use the second one same like this

```
public class Person : IDisposable
{
    public Person()
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = Id / a;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

and then

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            using var person = new Person();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when
        (ex.TargetSite.DeclaringType.Name == nameof(Person) &&
        ex.TargetSite.MemberType == System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Constructor)
        {
            Debug.Write("Error Constructor Person");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when
       (ex.TargetSite.DeclaringType.Name == nameof(Person) &&
       ex.TargetSite.MemberType != System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Constructor)
        {
            Debug.Write("Error Person");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Debug.Write("finally");
        }
    }
```

Comment: why you say from C#8.0 ?

Comment: @Grace because C# 8.0 added `using var x = ...` syntax