# SqlCommand.CommandTimeout is reached

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, timeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to catch SQLServer timeout exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664/how-to-catch-sqlserver-timeout-exceptions)

I have the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainDll"].ToString()))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandTimeout = 300;
        returnCode = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
        //Dispose();
    }
}
```

How do I know when the timeout has been reached? I want to grab it and do something with the SQL after the timeout.

Comment: It should throw an error when it reaches the command timeout.

Comment: new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainDll"].ToString()))

probably should be

   new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainDll"].ConnectionString)

Comment: @Raphael, this seems like a good link and I'll use this one

Comment: how do I catch an error with using?

Comment: @chris : wether inside the using, or "around" the using. Both are possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590490/try-catch-using-right-syntax

Comment: +1 for you help and thx @raphael

Answer (score 1):

You can only know the Timeout is reached when a error is thrown

So I would suggest is try to handle the exception and if TimeOut exception is caught thats the time you can do as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  //your code
}
catch (SqlException ex) {
  if (ex.Number == -2) { //System.Data.SqlClient.TdsEnums.TIMEOUT_EXPIRED
    //handle timeout
  }
  else {
    throw;
  }
}
finally {
  //cleanup
}
```

Source: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664/how-to-catch-sqlserver-timeout-exceptions) SO thread.