# When is DbConnection.StateChange called?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I have the following code:

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString");
        connection.Open();
        connection.StateChange += HandleSqlConnectionDrop;
        Console.WriteLine("Hi");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void HandleSqlConnectionDrop(object connection, StateChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DB change detected");
    }
}
```

I start the above code while the SQL server instance is running.  I then proceed to execute

```
SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT;
```

on the sql server instance that the program is connected to.  I then observer the SQL server service stopping.  However, I never see the "DB change detected" message in the output.  Why is this?

**Aside:** I will see the StateChange handler get called if I then attempt to perform an operation on the SQL connection, but never before hand.  Is there a way this behavior can be changed?

Comment: "I will see the StateChange handler get called if I then attempt to perform an operation on the SQL connection" - In fact you answer your question. Connection object doesn't ping server and check state only when needed. Place `connection.Open()` after `.StateChange+=...` to see that it works.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Shouldn't there be some sort of keep alive between the SQL client and the SQL server?  My understanding is that SqlConnection objects should map one-to-one to SQL server sessions.  If the server kills the session, is there a way that I can have that information passed to my code?

Comment: you could try to poll the server with something harmless like `select 1`

Comment: It is usually called when you try to send an sql command to you server, and the connection is broken or timed out. Since SqlConnection doesn't keep-alive the server, you may know that state changed only when you try to execute a command using this connection.

Comment: @v.chjen Is there some official documentation that you can point me to which supports the idea that "SqlConnection doesn't keep-alive the server"?

Answer (score 12):

> When is DbConnection.StateChange called?

You can find out by looking at the Microsoft reference source code.

The [`StateChange`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DBConnection.cs,191b2f1d559f7e8d) event is raised by the [`DbConnection.OnStateChange`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DBConnection.cs,bc9689aff46dc5bc,references) function. Looking for references to this function yields only a few instances:

Firstly, in the `SqlConnection` class, `OnStateChange` is called only in the [`Close`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs,9414944f8fe487ef,references) method.

Then in the [`DbConnectionHelper.cs`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionHelper.cs,9f986d2fc8fa438a) file, there's a partial class called `DBCONNECTIONOBJECT`. It looks like it's used for all `DbConnection`-derived classes using some build-time shenanigans. So you can consider it to be part of `SqlConnection`. In any case, it calls `OnStateChange` only from within the [`SetInnerConnectionEvent`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionHelper.cs,324) function.

As far as I can tell (the partial class nonsense makes it difficult), the `SqlConnection.SetInnerConnectionEvent` is only called from [`SqlConnectionFactory.SetInnerConnectionEvent`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnectionFactory.cs,049addc994565208,references). And *that* is called from:

- [`DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionClosed.cs.html#131)
- [`DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionInternal.cs,d0c96b80d6d7cbb0,references)
- [`DbConnectionInternal.CloseConnection`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionInternal.cs,478)

So, in summary - the event is only raised in response to client-side actions - there does not appear to be any polling of the connection-state built into `SQLConnection`.

> Is there a way this behavior can be changed?

Looking at the source code, I can't see one. As others have suggested, you could implement your own polling, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The `StateChange` event is meant for the state of the connection, not the instance of the database server. To get the state of the database server,

> The StateChange event occurs when the state of the event changes from
>   closed to opened, or opened to closed.

From MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.statechange(v=vs.110).aspx

If you're going to roll your own monitor for the database, then you may consider using a method that returns true/false if the connection is available and ping that method on a schedule. You could even wrap a method to do this in an endless loop repeating after a duration of time and raise it's own event when this "state" really changes then.

Here's a quick method from another SO answer that is a simple approach:

```
/// <summary>
/// Test that the server is connected
/// </summary>
/// <param name="connectionString">The connection string</param>
/// <returns>true if the connection is opened</returns>
private static bool IsServerConnected(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943871/4154421

Comment: "The StateChange event is meant for the state of the connection, not the instance of the database server." -> But if the state of the server changes, then the state of the connection should also change (i.e. become "no longer functional".)

Comment: But the connection won't detect the state change of the database server unless you actually query something against the server, which is why you should have a wrapper like noted in the answer so you have a reliable way to identify the true state changes and not just at your application layer.